# external hard drive Disk Unknown Not Initialized not detected

Tags: external-hard-drive

My seagate external hard drive is 500gb but shows 128PB , when i tried checking it on the windows cmd  using diskpart with the following commands

> list disk
>   select disk 1
>   clean all

I get this error:

DiskPart has encountered an error: The drive cannot find the sector requested.
See the System Event Log for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly some problem with the interface (USB connection) you're using.

1. First of all, you should try a different USB cable.
2. If that doesn't help, you should check if your HDD model has only an USB connector (soldered to the PCB of the HDD) or if a SATA connector is available.

If there is a SATA connector, you should try connecting the HDD directly using a SATA cable (you'll need access to a desktop computer).

3. If that doesn't help, you should try accessing the HDD using a Linux operating system (parted magic would be a good choice).

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you bro, i will try that out, i tried it inside a laptop and was same problem, couldnt format, i will try it on a desktop computer tomorow, btw do you know why it shows 128PB? while its 500GB , you think its not the hardisk but the connecter ,also , can i try it on kali linux? cuz im familiar with that , ty for the response

Comment: I never used kali linux (I know what it's for) but I think it should work.

128PB is the LBA limit according to the ATA/ATAPI-6 standard from 2003. 48 bits are used to specify the locations of blocks of data on the disk : so (2^48 * 512 bytes per sector) / 1024^5 = 128PB. I guess that the OS can't figure out what's the HDD capacity, so it's assuming the maximum possible.